# Mysql bad connection on the same laptop

Tags: mysql, go, database-connection

I use local mysql server from OpenServer for developing on Golang.

Sometimes I see errors "driver:bad connection"...
What may cause this problems?

Windows 10, OpenServer 5.2.2, Mysql server 5.6-x64, Golang 1.7.4, Ozzo-dbx 1.0.6

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the answer for my own question.
According to a study, this situation appear when debugger stops on breakpoints.
After this, I checked settings file for the MySql in OpenServer and found
`wait_timeout` parameter. Then I checked documentation on MySql website at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout and found default value for this (28800 instead 5 in OpenServer). When I changed the setting to the default value, the problem disappeared.